# Difference in understanding between Semaphore counter and semaphore methods integer parameter?

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore

I have got confused with Semaphore counter and formal parameter to semaphore methods like

`acquire(int parameter)`,`acquireUninterptbly(int parameter)`,`release(int parameter)`.

What happens if parameter is greater than semaphore counter and vice versa.
    It would be very helpful if someone explains by taking realtime example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Semaphore` has a certain number of permits available. If `acquire(int permits)` is called, the given number of permits are taken from the semaphore. If a semaphore does not have enough permits, the method will block/suspend the calling thread until enough permits are available.

If `release(int permits)` is called on the semaphore, the given number of permits are given back to the semaphore. If threads are waiting for permits (due to blocking `acquire` calls), they are woken up and try to gain their requested number of permits.

(Internally, the permits are nothing else than a thread safe numerical counter that is decreased or increased and can never be negative).

Usually, `aquire(int)` is interruptibly, so a thread `t`, that is waiting in `aquire(int)` can be interrupted by calling `t.interrupt()` from another thread. In this case, the blocking `aquire` call is terminated by an `InterruptedException`. If instead of `acquire` the method `aquireUninterruptibly` is used, this does NOT work.

For an example, have a look at the JavaDoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html

One thing about maximum number of permits: The semaphore is initialized with a certain number of permits available, but that does not mean that this is the maximum number of permits it can have. Theoretically, a thread could release more permits than it has aquired (or even release permits without calling `acquire` first). So it is allowed to call `aquire(int)` with more permits than the semaphore was initialized with, and to call `release(int)` giving back more permits than the semaphore ever had. The semantic of such calls is up to the programmer...